# Filter object array based on category and return list of matches React TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter

I am having trouble filtering an object array, based on a given property.

The object array looks something like this:

```
someData: [{
                id: "123",
                personData: [
                  {
                    personName: "John Smith",
                    personId: "125443",
                    categoryId: "B1",
                    description: "description"
                  }}]}];
```

I want to group the personData based on the categoryId, but represent the category grouping by its categoryName (instead of Id as this will not make much sense to the user).

There are a series of categories which are contained in a json in the following format:

```
const groups = {
  data: [
    {
      categoryName: "Banking",
      categoryId: "B1",
      description: "Financial sector"
    },
    {
      categoryName: "Retail",
      categoryId: "R1",
      description: "Retail and customer experience"
    }
  ]
};
```

How would I go about filtering based on these conditions? All help is much appreciated! I am using react and typescript

Once filtered the data should look like this:

```
Banking
    personName: John Smith
    personId: 125443

Retail
   personName: Judie Smith
   personId: 124938
```

Comment: Can you fill in the example JSON so it is a bit more clear how the `personData` should be mapped?

Comment: @slashmelon thanks, have added some more details, hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You can try groupBy on that person data.

```
const products = [
 { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' },
 { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
 { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
];

const groupByCategory = products.groupBy(product => {
    return product.category;
});

console.log(groupByCategory);
// {
//   'fruits': [
//     { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' }, 
//     { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
//   ],
//   'vegetables': [
//     { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
//   ]
// }
```

Comment: have you tested this. where does groupBy come from

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupBy

As per the docs. And yes this works on node 17.x

Comment: i see. must be something very new as it is still not supported by most browsers

Comment: Or you may see a rough implementation here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think something along the lines of this function would return what you need.

```
const data = [
    {
      categoryName: "Banking",
      categoryId: "B1",
      description: "Financial sector"
    },
    {
      categoryName: "Retail",
      categoryId: "R1",
      description: "Retail and customer experience"
    }
];

function groupByProperty(arrayOfObjects, property) {
  return arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const key = curr[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(curr);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const dataByCategoryName = groupByProperty(data, "categoryName");
console.log(dataByCategoryName);

/* Output
{
    Banking: [{
        categoryId: "B1",
        categoryName: "Banking",
        description: "Financial sector"
    }],
    Retail: [{
        categoryId: "R1",
        categoryName: "Retail",
        description: "Retail and customer experience"
    }]
}
*/
```